# Choosing fake coin n+1 times

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory

There are $K+1$ boxes with $K$ coins in each. $i$-th box contains $i-1$ true coins and $K+1-i$ fake coins. A person chooses a box (probability of choosing boxes is equally likely). Then he makes $n$ times his experiment: chooses the coin and puts it back in the box. What is the probability $P_K(n)$, probability that on $n+1$ time the person chooses fake coin provided that previous $n$ times he chose fake coins. Find $\lim_{K \to \infty}P_K(n)$.

$P_K(n) = \mathbb{P}(n+1 \ fake \ |  \ n \ fake \ \land \ ... \ \land 1 \ fake) =\\ \mathbb{P}(n+1 \ fake \ \land 1 \ box \ | \  n \ fake \ \land \ ... \ \land 1 \ fake) \ + \ ... \ + \mathbb{P}(n+1 \ fake \ \land K+1 \ box \ | \  n \ fake \ \land \ ... \ \land 1 \ fake) = \\
\cfrac{\mathbb{P}(n+1 \ fake \ \land \  n \ fake \ \land \ ... \ \land 1 \ fake \ \land 1 \ box)}{\mathbb{P}(n \ fake \ \land \ ... \ \land 1 \ fake)}  \ + \ ... \ + \ \cfrac{\mathbb{P}(n+1 \ fake \ \land \  n \ fake \ \land \ ... \ \land 1 \ fake \ \land K+1 \ box)}{\mathbb{P}(n \ fake \ \land \ ... \ \land 1 \ fake)} = \\
\cfrac{K}{K}\cdot \cfrac{1}{K+1} \ + \ ... \ + \ \cfrac{0}{K}\cdot \cfrac{1}{K+1} = \cfrac{1}{K+1}\cdot \cfrac{1+K}{2}\cdot \cfrac{K}{K} = \cfrac{1}{2}\\$

Is my reasoning correct?

The answer should be $\cfrac{n+1}{n+2}$, the grader said that the solution is not correct as `Your answer does not take into account that box remains the same`. What's wrong with my solution?

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: The work-up could be simplified by simply noting that since the fake coins are returned to the box between each pick, the earlier $n$ picks have no influence on pick $n+1$. Thus $n+1$ picks is a red herring and you can do the calculation for just a single pick. But you still end up with the same calculation.